# set pagesize limit for Getrequest using Java in Rally rest API

Tags: rally, rallyapi

THe question i have is i am trying to get all the userstories related to a release, i created a query request for type release and got the ref to workproduct.

so i got something like this from the query response "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Release/12345678/WorkProducts"
Now I am use this in my GET REQUEST to get all the user stories related to the Release.
The response is giving only 20 user stories since the default page size is 20.
Is there a way to increase the page size for get request.

the code is something like this :

```
QueryRequest iterationRequest = new QueryRequest("release");
iterationRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "Workspace", "WorkProducts","Feature"));
iterationRequest.setWorkspace("/workspace/12345678");
iterationRequest.setProject("/project/4567890");
iterationRequest.setPageSize(200);
iterationRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", Release));
QueryResponse iterationQueryResponse = restApi.query(iterationRequest);
JsonArray iterationQueryResults = iterationQueryResponse.getResults();
JsonElement iterationQueryElement = iterationQueryResults.get(0);
JsonObject iterationQueryObject = iterationQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject workprodobj = iterationQueryObject.get("WorkProducts").getAsJsonObject();
String workprodref = workprodobj.get("_ref").getAsString();
System.out.println("workprodref :" + workprodref);

GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(workprodref);
getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID"));
GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);

The response output is like this 
{"QueryResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "TotalResultCount": 120, "StartIndex": 1, "PageSize": 20,
"Results": [{"_rallyAPIMajor": "2","_rallyAPIMinor": "0","_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/123456789",
"_refObjectUUID": "xxxxxx",
"_objectVersion": "1",
"_refObjectName": "obj name removed masked",
"FormattedID": "US123456",
"DirectChildrenCount": 0,
} .....
```

Can we change the page size from 20 to 200  for a getrequest??

Answer (score 0):

`GetRequest` extends `Request` which has method `addParam(String, String)` which can be used to pass get parameters into the encoded URL, such as setting page size.

```
getRequest.addParam("pagesize", "200")
```

ref: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blob/542afa16ea44c9c64cebb0299500dcbbb50b6d7d/src/main/java/com/rallydev/rest/request/Request.java#L54